# How to pass an argument to a Javascript Module?

Tags: javascript, module, jsm

I want to use a [Javascript Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules) (JSM) in a single window of my Xul application, so I can load the resource as I need it.

But, I need to pass the window to the JSM, and I don't know how to do it. Follows my attempt:

In my **resource.jsm**:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["hello"];

function hello(win) {
    win.alert("ALERT FROM JSM!");
}
```

calling in my window with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://module/resource.jsm");
hello(window);
```

but I get:

> win is undefined

in the resource.jsm.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you first assign `window = window`? I remember hearing about some really strange issues with certain "pre-defined" global variables that were (somehow) settled with a self-assignment...

Comment: @Platinum Azure I got the same error message.

Comment: @Platinum Azure I think what you saw were this [page's samples](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/Modules).

Comment: No, it was about setTimeout... Sorry. I knew it was a long shot, hence putting it in a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be causing problems that you named the parameter for your `hello` function to be `window`.  While window isn't a reserved word, most browser environments treat it as an unassignable constant of sorts.  Try:

```
function hello( obj ) {
    obj.alert("ALERT FROM JSM!");
}
```

in your module and then invoke it with `hello(window)`, `hello(document.window)`, or `hello(this)`

---

After reading the Javascript Module documentation, it looks like you'll need to create an object within the module and then change it's property by reference.  So in your JSM:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["params", "hello"];

params = {
  win: this
};

function hello() {
    params.win.alert("ALERT FROM JSM!");
}
```

Then you'd invoke by first assigning the window to that parameter and then calling the function:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://module/resource.jsm");
params.win = window;
hello();
```

Note: I am not familiar enough with JSMs to know if there's a better way to do this, but this should work.

Comment: Updated answer with an alternate solution.

Comment: Very good observation. But I got `params.win.alert is not a function`. And by declaring `param.win` as `null` I realized that it was not assigned, as I got `params.win is null` on the `alert()` call. Something is wrong before (or on) the assignment.. (I will post here if I find what)

Comment: Oh, gosh, some of my tests were bad because I didn't update the build-id, so it was running something cached, out-of-date. Now it's working, and can even pass the window as a parameter normally. Thanks for work on this with me!